# Database of numbers

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

I have found so far 4 references to databases of numbers.

- [Perfect Numbers List](https://web.archive.org/web/20090503154707/http://amicable.homepage.dk/perfect.htm) (but the larger numbers have broken links, so I haven't been able to find the actual text string of all the perfect numbers)
- [Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org)
- [The first 50 million primes](https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/millions/)
- A webpage which I can't seem to find which had the first 10,000 numbers listed with a brief sentence explaining something cool about that number.

What I would like to know is (1) if there are any other databases of numbers out there for free use, and (2) if there are any copies of the perfect numbers in their full form available for free.

Answer (score 1):

For the list of perfect numbers, the wikipedia entry list all known (51 at this time) perfect numbers:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_perfect_numbers

There is the Cunningham factorizations, which is the database of factors $f$ of the numbers $a^n \pm 1$ at http://homes.cerias.purdue.edu/~ssw/cun/ under "The Main Tables".

There are databases on number fields available at https://hobbes.la.asu.edu/NFDB/, where you can find information on say class numbers and class groups.